# Find time between mono runnable subscribe call and runnable actually being executed

Tags: rxjs, reactive-programming, project-reactor, reactor

I have a mono created from a runnable. I am using an ExecutorService with fixed thread size to create Scheduler instance. I am creating multiple Mono's using below code and subscribing to them.

```
Mono.fromRunnable(new Runnable() {
//Some business logic
}).subscribeOn(scheduler)
```

These subscriptions can happen parallel due to invocations from multiple calls and we are using a common ExecutorService for all these invocations, there could be possibility of lag between when it is subscribed and when "Some business logic" block mentioned below is actually executed due to limited thread size set for ExecutorService. Is there a way to find this time lag between when it is subscribed and when it actually got a thread to be executed?

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in way that I know of, so the best you'll likely do is use `doOnSubscribe()` (on the `Mono` object) to save one timestamp, and then create another timestamp as the first line of the `run()` method in that `Runnable`.

Those timestamps can then be compared to work out what, if any, lag is present.

Comment: Hey Michael, I tried this but both doOnSubscribe() and runnable are being executed by same thread after it is being assigned. So, it doesn't give the lag details which I was expecting.

Comment: try using `doFirst` rather than `doOnSubscribe`, which triggers on the `Subscriber#onSubscribe` method (which is already too late in the lifecycle, compared to the influence of `.subscribeOn(Scheduler)`). edit: also make sure that `doFirst` is _after_ `subscribeOn`